# Route in Laravel Blade show double prefix

Tags: laravel, routes

I'm new in Laravel and now I'm trying to make link in my blade files.
I read that in many tutorials, you can just use `href="{{route('mm-admin/blog')}}"` to make it works.
And by works I mean the list should be like this `"mm-admin/blog"`.
But what i get using that code is `"mm-admin/mm-admin/blog"`.

I tried to remove the `mm-admin` from this code `"route('mm-admin/blog')"` and it returns error saying

> blog isn't defined.

what is wrong with my code??

this is my blade file

```php
<li class="{{ request()->is('mm-admin/dashboard') ? 'active' : '' }}">
    <a href="{{route('dashboard')}}">
       <i class="fas fa-home"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

and this is my web route

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => 'mm-admin', 'as' => 'mm-admin.'], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'Admin\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    Route::get('/login', 'Admin\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
    Route::post('/proseslogin', 'Admin\LoginController@login');
    Route::get('/blog', [
        'as'   => 'blog',
        'uses' => 'Admin\BlogController@index', 'middleware' => 'admin',
    ]);
});
```

Comment: you can try my package https://github.com/ManojKiranA/Aktiv

Comment: try Rouhollah answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55773143/386868 )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
href="{{route('mm-admin.blog')}}"
```